# How to get the contents inside a XML tag to create an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jquery-selectors

Here is the `XML` file:

```
<SketchPad>
<Player>
    <TotalPage>2</TotalPage>
    <BackgroundImage>/Users/ltlab/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/D84490FE-3450-456C-A8FE-16BE8B1EB12C/Documents/publicUser_1356864779.441782_local.png</BackgroundImage>
    <Name>1</Name>
    <SelfBackgroundImage>sound.png</SelfBackgroundImage>
    <Type>Record</Type>
    <X_Value>0.000000</X_Value>
    <Y_Value>38.000000</Y_Value>
    <Height_Value>50.000000</Height_Value>
    <Width_Value>50.000000</Width_Value>
    <File_Path>null</File_Path>
</Player>
<Player>
    <TotalPage>2</TotalPage>
    <BackgroundImage>/Users/ltlab/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/D84490FE-3450-456C-A8FE-16BE8B1EB12C/Documents/publicUser_1356864779.441782_local.png</BackgroundImage>
    <Name>1</Name>
    <SelfBackgroundImage>8_128x128.png</SelfBackgroundImage>
    <Type>Stamp</Type>
    <X_Value>7.000000</X_Value>
    <Y_Value>716.000000</Y_Value>
    <Height_Value>80.000000</Height_Value>
    <Width_Value>80.000000</Width_Value>
    <File_Path>null</File_Path>
</Player>
<Player>
    <TotalPage>2</TotalPage>
    <BackgroundImage>/Users/ltlab/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/D84490FE-3450-456C-A8FE-16BE8B1EB12C/Documents/publicUser_1356864779.441782_local.png</BackgroundImage>
    <Name>1</Name>
    <SelfBackgroundImage>duck.png</SelfBackgroundImage>
    <Type>Stamp</Type>
    <X_Value>570.000000</X_Value>
    <Y_Value>715.000000</Y_Value>
    <Height_Value>80.000000</Height_Value>
    <Width_Value>80.000000</Width_Value>
    <File_Path>null</File_Path>
</Player>
</SketchPad>
```

What I want to do is to collect all the data inside the tag .

```
$(xml).find("X_Value").toArray();
```

But it returns an array still containing the tag like this:

`[<x_value>0.0000000<x_value>,<x_value>7.0000000<x_value>,<x_value>570.0000000<x_value>]`

Not an expected array:
`[0.0000000,7.0000000,570.0000000]`

How can I do to directly extract the values inside the tag, making an array?

I don't really know how to manipulate the `jQuery.map()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead...

```
$(xml).find("X_Value").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
```

Your previous example is getting a reference to those elements. This replaces the references with the inner text.

Comment: Does $(this) reference to the <x_value>0.0000000<x_value>? And the ".text()" get the content:"0.0000000". And in each iteration, does the method get()  collect these value? But I don't see any array declaration here. 
Can I just write var content_arr= $(xml).find("X_Value").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get(); to create the target array?

Comment: @Stallman Yes. Map replaces its slots with the return values. `get()` is just a cheap way to get an array, `toArray()` (like your example) would also work.

Comment: You said get() is just a cheap way to get an array, but what if we don't declare a variable to receive it? In that condition, we can manipulate the data array. I thought.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Stallman It will still return an array, only it won't be assigned to a variable. So it will hang around until it's GC'd.

Comment: @Stallman [Garbage Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). When you don't have any pointers to an object or value in JavaScript, and that memory needs to be reclaimed, a process will mark that memory as free which will allow future things to occupy that space.